# Doesn't Linux have a special bit in the page table of processes to stop instructions to run in the stack therefore stopping overflow attacks?

Tags: linux, memory

So the guy in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S0aBV-Waeo

overflowed the stack, tampered the return address, pointed it in the stack and copied the executable code in the stack with a NOP slip

but i thought all the modern linux systems including debian ones have a defense against this using a NX (not-executable) type of bit in the page table and by using that stopping instructions like that  to work in stack? or am i missing something?

Comment: That offhand remark about the Z shell isn't really accurate. It's a year younger than the Bourne Again shell and just as (un)protected.

Comment: Also note that non-executable stack is mentioned in the presentation.  Watch _all_ of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non executable pages (NX-bit) is a hardware feature. It allows operating system to mark which pages can be executed. Processor faults if the program attempts to execute code in non-executable memory page.

Additionally, whether the stack is/is not executable depends also on the compiler options (and the resulting binary). Modern Linux distributions enable many hardening techniques for userspace binaries, such as non-executable stacks, stack canaries, address space layout randomization. For example [Ubuntu userspace hardening](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#Userspace_Hardening).

It is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867982/8270535) to compile your binaries with executable stack and without stack canaries to make stack overflows possible, as  was done for the video example (couldn't see the program compiled/what options were used, but by default gcc should not enable executable stacks for such a simple program).

Additionally, SELinux (and other Linux Security Modules) can also be  configured to prevent system from running binaries which require executable+writable memory (heap or stack).

Comment: But i thought there should be a hardware support for this based on answers on other questions? do you mean both the compiler and hardware should support this? if so, do all the modern compilers do this or..?

Comment: NX bit is hardware feature, processor faults if memory marked NX is attempted to execute. Additionally software running on the platform also needs to take advantage of it; the operating system marking the pages (stack/other areas) non-executable. Some programs might require executable-writable memory (in stack or heap), and attempt to enable it on load or run-time. In the end the OS can refuse allocating such memory for the program. On architectures which do not support NX access bit it sometimes is possible to [emulate it in software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703055/).

Answer (score 1):

The NX bit was only introduced in the x86_64 architecture, it doesn't exist in the 32-bit Intel/AMD processors. Of course, practically everyone is running 64-bit PCs nowadays, but nobody seems to have informed the bloggers and vloggers out there who still insist on explaining things in the context of the old 386 world.

Comment: In fairness, the video is explicitly explaining what a buffer overflow exploit is.  That is its title.  It does no good to explain it using a system where it is (partly) prevented from happening.

Comment: So basically if that guy tried that same attack with a 64 bit modern intel/amd it wouldn't work?

Comment: The exact attack would not work with the NX bit set. But the NX bit is not a panacea, it just prevents execution. Overwriting the return address with the address of some existing code would still work.

Comment: @JohanMyréen thanks for answer! but one question, if the return address is  not pointing to our stack/heap then where? inside another process? in that case   i thought the process's virtual memory space is for the running process only and we only have access to this virtual memory with our process, what am i missing? and it cannot be inside our code section because then the program in infected itself

Comment: Into the code section of the current process, where you can find "interesting" places to return to. Remember that the program has to be buggy in the first place.  You will have to find a vulnerable program first, you can't code the overflow vulnerability yourself, that would only be shooting yourself in the foot. This is not as easy as the sensationalist videos out there let you believe it is. Several other countermeasures have been developed, e.g. address space randomisation (ASLR). See the Wikipedia artcle on Return Oriented Programming.

Comment: AFAIK, the NX bit is usable on 32-bit x86, if PAE is enabled.

Comment: @ilkkachu The NX bit is present on later PAE enabled 32-bit processors. It was not present on the Pentium Pro (1995), which was the first processor with PAE. [Intel implemented the similar XD bit feature in x86 processors beginning with the Pentium 4 processors based on later iterations of the Prescott core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit#x86) (2004).

Comment: @JohanMyréen but even if we return it to the code section of the program itself, how can it be so badly written that the code itself become a payload? like the software developer himself wrote a malicious code or..?!

Comment: The function to be returned to can also be a library function. For example, you could return to the libc `system` function. Look for a string in the program containing `/bin/bash` and pass a pointer to that string to `system`. As I said earlier, this is not as straightforward as some people try to make you believe it is, but crackers are smart people with a vivid imagination and a lot of time on their hands.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, right, so it does exist on 32-bit Intel/AMD processors, even if not all of them.